# Can we select the time the current transaction began?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Does MySQL (InnoDB) provide a way to select the moment the current transaction was started?

Of course, we could somehow capture the time manually, but the idea is to avoid the need for running an extra query (like `SELECT NOW()`) at the beginning of the transaction.

Comment: ....why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: I have one specific case where such info, if stored, could be useful for observability purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I'm aware of is this:

```
SELECT trx_started
FROM information_schema.innodb_trx
WHERE trx_mysql_thread_id = connection_id()
```

One potential limitation of that query is `trx_started` is rounded to seconds (no milliseconds precision).

Would love to here about alternative options.

Comment: Why, what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: According to MySQL doc about [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-events-transactions-current-table.html), there is a table storing a current transactions. Try that, and check if there is a solution you can make

Comment: @Shadow I'm not sure if it's bad, but there might be better alternatives out there.

Comment: @SaulUribe thanks for this. BTW here is the newer [MySQL 8 version of your link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-events-transactions-current-table.html). It's about reading from `performance_schema.events_transactions_current`. I'd prefer to avoid depending on `performance_schema`, as it's not always available. But thanks for the suggestion, it might be useful in certain situations for other readers.

Comment: Hmmm...  `events_transactions_current.TIMER_START` looks like milliseconds, but it is about 5 years out of date.

Comment: Even if that worked, it would be an "extra query".

Comment: @RickJames the point is, you can put that query as a sub-query to an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` statement (for example), in which case you wouldn't need to have run an extra (standalone) query to MySQL at the beginning of the transaction.

Comment: @at54321 - `INSERT INTO t (start_time. ...) VALUES (NOW(6), ...)` -- Don't need a subquery nor a Join.  Similarly for `UPDATE`.

Comment: @RickJames the idea is to create a TX, do some stuff and _then_ run the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement. Sorry if that didn't become clear. If that "some stuff" began with a `SELECT`, I might also be able to take advantage of it and put one `NOW(6)` in there, but that's not the case.